# VBA UsedRanges when 0

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to put something together where it looks in a column range, copy's that column (Minus 2 rows of headers) then pastes it into Sheet2 under the last used row. The problem comes in when there is nothing to copy from the range in sheet1. I was thinking of an If statement using a count but I figured there has to be a better way to do this. Here is what I have currently (sorry it's a little messy).

```
 Sub CopyUsedRanges()

 Dim lrow As Long
 Dim sh As Worksheet
 Dim rng As Range

 Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet1")
 On Error Resume Next

   'First
    lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = sh.UsedRange.Range("A3:C" & lrow)
    Set rng = rng.Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'Second
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = sh.UsedRange.Range("E3:G" & lrow)
    Set rng = rng.Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'Third
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = sh.UsedRange.Range("I3:K" & lrow).Offset(1, 0)
    Set rng = rng.Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'Fourth
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = sh.UsedRange.Range("M3:O" & lrow)
    Set rng = rng.Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


End Sub
```

Comment: Why use `UsedRange` with a set range?

Comment: Just use `if lrow>=3 then`   Also, there is no need for all the activating, selecting and copying etc, you can just say `worksheets("Destination").range("A1:A10").value=worksheets("Source").range("A1:A10").value`

Comment: I'm using it cause I'm copying from set ranges on Sheet1 into the a set range in Sheet1 not the same ranges. Example Range E:G - headers(2rows) from sheet1 pasted into range A:C in Sheet2, Then Range I:K in sheet1 to next available line in range A:C on sheet2

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Thanks for tip! I actually was trying to use the IF >3 then my problem was the goto because it's limited and I do have several ranges to copy from.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Is there a way to setup the destination so it is placing on the next available row within Columns A:C using your suggestion? I've been playing around with it but it doesn't seem to like     `.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).value`  being added to the mix

Comment: Got it to work, thanks for all the help! used the following 
    `Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Range("A2:C" & lrow - 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:C" & lrow).Value`

Answer (score 1):

This should get you what you need:

```
Sub CopyUsedRanges()
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet

    Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    'First
    sh1.Activate
    lrow = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If lrow > 2 Then
        sh1.Range("A3:C" & lrow).Copy sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End If

    'Second
    lrow = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    If lrow > 2 Then
        sh1.Range("E3:G" & lrow).Copy sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End If

    'Third
    lrow = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    If lrow > 2 Then
        sh1.Range("I3:K" & lrow).Offset(1, 0).Copy sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End If

    'Fourth
    lrow = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    If lrow > 2 Then
        sh1.Range("M3:O" & lrow).Copy sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End If

End Sub
```